# Clarifying English Writing Conventions

Tags: punctuation, grammar, conventions

I need example and usage of the following.

- "but" - I seen it used but without comma, but after comma, and new sentence with But. What's the proper way to use it.
- "However" - I seen it used start of a sentence and in middle of sentence with commas like "It's like this, however, It's also like that..." - What is the correct usage?
- I want to know how are ";" is used.
- I want to know how are "..." is used.
- Quotes. I seen that periods are wrapped into the quotations like this "Example." and not outside of the quotes like "This". Which is the proper usage? What else comes at the end and is wrapped by quotations? How to start a new sentence when in a situation like the example.
- I want to learn of the proper usage of hyphen i.e. "-" in a sentence.
- Do all lists go like this "a, b, c, d, and e" or "a, b, c, d and e" - which is appropriate?

I guess that covers all my doubts with writing conventions. I'll be grateful to anyone who can help.

---

*Note:*

If I posted this on the wrong site, please feel free to move it.

Comment: This question is not about writing but English usage and would be a better fit on English Language Learners. Can we move it?

Comment: *"This question is not about writing but English usage and would be a better fit on English Language Learners. Can we move it?"* **Yes**

Comment: Hi Mafuyu-Chama. It looks like you might have created two accounts. I recommend that you follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in our [Help] to have them merged.

Comment: It's also far better to make sure your question focuses on one specific issue, and to ask multiple separate questions if you have multiple issues you need to deal with. For example, your question about quotes would seem to be covered by our existing question [Period outside quotation marks …?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/24090/2533)

Comment: Hi, Mafuyu-Chama. You're asking several questions about the fundamentals of English usage, something that's not on-topic here. However, these questions have already been addressed on the English site: [What is the proper way of using triple dots and spaces before/after them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/26240/161), [Comma before 'but'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/393348/161), [How does one correctly use a semicolon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92/161) (continued below)

Comment: [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1560/161) [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113422/161)

Comment: Also, welcome to the site! Please have a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, and I hope you stick around!